# How to pass parameters to php using get JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a `json_data.php` file and I want to pass a parameter to a function inside a switch statement using `getJSON`.

```
<?php
 require_once "Db.php";
 $db = new Db();

 if(isset($_GET['method'])) {
    switch (($_GET['method'])) {
       case 'getUserIds':
          echo json_encode($db -> getUserIds());
          exit();

       case 'getUser':
          echo json_encode($db -> getUser($userId) {
          exit();



       // other cases go here
       case 'getCertCategories':
          echo json_encode($db -> getCertCategories());
          exit();

       case 'get
       default:
          break;
    }

 }
```

How do I pass a parameter so I can pass `$userId` to the `getUser` function?

Comment: Syntax error near `getUser()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `$.getJSON` is an object containing query parameters.

```
$.getJSON('json_data.php', { method: 'getUserIds' }, function(response) {
    ...
});

$.getJSON('json_data.php', { method: 'getUser', userId: 'joe' }, function(response) {
    ...
});
```

In PHP, you would access `$_GET['method']`, `$_GET['userId']`, etc.